# How can I remove a JS event listener without access to the context in which it was created?

Tags: javascript, event-listener, confluence

My company uses Confluence for its internal wiki, which is fine, except that the editor has some keyboard shortcuts bound that drive me up the wall. In particular, it uses ^K for "insert link", when I want it to honor the system default behavior of "kill line".

I've tracked down the relevant code that inserts the listener:

```
$("#markupTextarea").select(function () {
    AJS.Editor.storeTextareaBits(true);
}).keyup(function (e) {
    AJS.Editor.contentChangeHandler();

    if (e.ctrlKey) {
        if (e.keyCode == 75) {// bind ctrl+k to insert link
            return openLinkPopup(e);
        }
        if (e.keyCode == 77) {// bind ctrl+m to insert image
            $("#editor-insert-image").click();
            return false;
        }
    }
}).keydown(function (e) {
    // prevent firefox's default behaviour
    if (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 75) {
        return AJS.stopEvent(e);
    }
}).change(function () {
    AJS.Editor.contentChangeHandler();
});
```

For context, it seems like they're using a customized version of TinyMCE. Ideally, I'd like a userscript for Chrome that nukes these event listeners, but I can't even get them to go away by doing things to them in the Chrome JS console.

Things I've tried (mostly at other people's suggestion; I'm not exactly a stellar JS hacker):

`$('markupTextarea').unbind('select')` -- says `Object #<HTMLTextAreaElement> has no method 'unbind'`

`$('markupTextarea').removeEventListener` -- doesn't work since I don't have a name to reference these listeners by

I'm pretty much out of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Your `$` isn't jQuery.

Write  `jQuery('#markupTextarea').unbind('select')`.

Comment: SLaks - the OP infers that *markupTextarea* is an id, your answer has it as a tagName. Minor point but worth correcting.